# Django container unable to connect to other container on the same network

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose, dns

I'm very new to docker, now I am trying to run django with mysql in docker through docker-compose, but I always get this error:

`ping: mysql: Name or service not known`

I am using `Docker version 24.0.4, build 3713ee1` and `Docker Compose version v2.17.3`

I have read the documentation it says

> When you run docker compose up, the following happens:
>
> A network called myapp_default is created.
> A container is created using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name web.
> A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name db.

Here is my docker-compose file that I am using;

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  backend:
    container_name: analytics_api
    build:
      context: .
    command: gunicorn analytics_api.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --timeout 120 --workers 4
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - "mysql:database"

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

Also I have checked the network and it has both the containers in there

```
[
    {
        "Name": "radioapis_default",
        "Id": "7a3a7a38886f7e19bdd6e3642bc9cf0b48fb6376c171a3ccae2cacde00b3f329",
        "Created": "2023-07-24T12:58:10.131998722Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "3ff18b9f499a2fc8b0bbd6bc9d1d7e5316e54cb9a849445360a468d01467bcbe": {
                "Name": "radioapis-mysql-1",
                "EndpointID": "049578e968da8d1807ea4ac04ec06e0480833f08f365da184d30bfe36a8ccb4c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "4b804645be9d383ca097b8186636aea03489eba3b29cf9fd50444ffe0137b78e": {
                "Name": "analytics_api",
                "EndpointID": "770c0d63d786bc851e961f1fa0143b582da0ae0be6c14988c089a4525a012408",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "radioapis",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.17.3"
        }
    }
```

I have tried using a network in docker-compose.yml file;

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - shared_network

  backend:
    container_name: analytics_api
    build:
      context: .
    command: gunicorn analytics_api.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --timeout 120 --workers 4
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - "mysql:database"
    networks:
      - shared_network

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  shared_network:
```

But still to no use.

Comment: What code runs `ping`, and why?  The `links:` option is obsolete and I've seen it implicated in some trouble in the past; does deleting that make any difference?

Comment: I am running ping myself from the container shell to check connectivity.

Comment: I don't think that makes sense as an operation: a database server won't answer ICMP ECHO packets, and it doesn't quite make sense to get an interactive shell inside a GUnicorn server.  Does your application successfully connect to its database?

Comment: I am using the same on another project and it works.

Comment: The problem is when using  `'HOST': 'mysql'` in my django settings it can not resolve 'mysql'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved as I did not know the actual difference between `docker run` and `docker exec`.

As `docker run` is the command you use to create a new container from an image in an isolated network separate from the already running container, whilst `docker exec` lets you run commands on an already running container.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your compose file and it works , i don't know about your api and how it queries the database. the problem may be with that.

make sure that the name of the service `mysql` can be resolved by the other container , you can test it with :

```
docker exec -it analytics_api sh
```

i don't know your api image , you might need to replace `sh` with some other shell.

then inside the container :

```
curl -v mysql
<or>
nslookup mysql
```

if the hostname get resolved its ok.
else you might need to see your docker networking or make a network manually and use that.

hope that helps!

Comment: It has returned me this 

`root@4b804645be9d:/analytics# curl -v mysql
*   Trying 172.22.0.2:80...
* connect to 172.22.0.2 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to mysql port 80 after 2 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mysql port 80 after 2 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

Comment: I have also tried another network in docker-compose.yml but to no use.

Comment: The hostname can be resolved as you see. Is your app connecting to the correct port of mysql?

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to the 3306 port. If you are , everything is fine with rhe connection , check your code for further details. I hope i've helped

Comment: Ideally my django container should be able to connect to it using its name and I have assigned the port 3306 in django database settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with DNS resolution when trying to connect to the mysql container

```
ping: mysql: Name or service not known
```

this error message means that hostname "mysql" cannot be resolved to an ip address.

you shouldn't use links in docker compose when you're using networks.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - shared_network

  backend:
    container_name: analytics_api
    build:
      context: .
    command: gunicorn analytics_api.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --timeout 120 --workers 4
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - shared_network

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  shared_network:
```

make sure to recreate the containers using "docker-compose up --build"

use the service name you defined in docker-compose.yml as your hostname in Django configuration

and since you mentioned that you are new to docker I just want to mention that you should specify a version tag for mysql image instead of using the latest tag as best practice

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Tried this and still having the same issue. It is strange that this config wont work but the same config works on another project.